# Does Indexing a View in Sql Server 2008 actually duplicate the original data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexed-view, indexed-views

If i create an Indexed View (in Sql Server 2008), does this mean i copy all required the data from the source tables into a separate new table? Or are only some tiny pointers/indexes saved, to represent this view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the data is copied and stored separately, so if you modify the underlying table, your indexed view will update automatically.  [This causes a lot of lock contention](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/02/be-ready-to-drop-your-indexed-view.aspx). Also the indexed view may grow larger than the underlying tables and become counterproductive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the data is copied. Other database platforms such as Oracle refer to this as a [Materialized View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) because the data will [materialize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/materialize) into a physical form.

Answer (score 2):

When a unique clustered index is created on a view, the result set is stored in the database just like a table with a clustered index is stored.

As modifications are made to the data in the base tables, the data modifications are reflected in the data stored in the indexed view

~ from msdn

Comment: So the answer is ... 'Yes -the data is duplicated' ... ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (undocumented but widely used) `DBCC PAGE` command to see exactly what is stored. The following will create an indexed view and print the contents of the first data page.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dbcc_ind') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE #dbcc_ind
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE #dbcc_ind
    (PageFID  TINYINT, 
    PagePID INT,   
    IAMFID   TINYINT, 
    IAMPID  INT, 
    ObjectID  INT,
    IndexID  TINYINT,
    PartitionNumber TINYINT,
    PartitionID BIGINT,
    iam_chain_type  VARCHAR(30),    
    PageType  TINYINT, 
    IndexLevel  TINYINT,
    NextPageFID  TINYINT,
    NextPagePID  INT,
    PrevPageFID  TINYINT,
    PrevPagePID INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (PageFID, PagePID));

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vtest') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE dbo.vtest (
i INT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
c1 CHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT REPLICATE('x',500), 
c2 CHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT REPLICATE('y',500) 
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.vtest DEFAULT VALUES
GO 10

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ixViewTest') IS NULL
BEGIN
EXEC('CREATE VIEW dbo.ixViewTest
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT i,c1,c2
FROM dbo.vtest;')
EXEC('CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [cix] ON [dbo].[ixViewTest] ([i] ASC)')
END
GO


DECLARE @command VARCHAR(1000)
SET @command = 'DBCC IND(' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + ', ixViewTest,1) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;'

INSERT INTO #dbcc_ind
    EXEC ( @command );


SELECT @command= 'DBCC PAGE (' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + ',' + CAST(PageFID AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(PagePID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',1) ;'
FROM #dbcc_ind
WHERE PageType=1
 AND PrevPagePID=0


DBCC TRACEON(3604)
EXEC ( @command )
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604)
```